# Height of UITableViewCell based on NSAttributedText

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code for getting the height of UITableViewCell based on NSAttributedText:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)pTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake([pTableView bounds].size.width, 100.0F);
    NSAttributedString *text = [self.tableSource getData:[indexPath row]];
    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:nil];
    return rect.size.height;
}
```

The attributed text has the following attributes:

```
Country *c = [countryArray objectAtIndex:row];
NSMutableAttributedString *data = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:c.name];
[data addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:30.0F]  range:NSMakeRange(0, [c.name length])];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopyWithZone:nil];
paraStyle.headIndent = 2.0F;
paraStyle.tailIndent = -2.0F;
paraStyle.lineSpacing = 20.0F;
[data addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paraStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [c.name length])];
return data;
```

Single-lined cells are giving me a height of 33.0F and some are giving me a height of 53.0F. Two lined cells are giving me more height but they are consistent. Why are the single-lined cells giving an inconsistent height of 33.0F and 53.0F?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It should be because if the alphabets, say "y" & "g" and "h" & "l". Is causing this. Check alphabets in text when u get 53.0F as height

Comment: Afghanistan has a g but its height is 33. Albania has a height of 53.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired effect by using minimum line height:

```
   NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopyWithZone:nil];
    paraStyle.minimumLineHeight = 46.0F;
    [data addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paraStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [c.name length])];
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure you accept your answer, so the question doesn't show as unanswered.